# Trying to work with boot strap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to replicate this code to learn how boot strap works:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RcDN/)

However instead of a button, i am using an image. When I click the image it highlights, however the modal does not show. I have been going over modal examples from different sources and they are all different. I cant seem to apply any of them to work.

Am I supposed to use jquery to actually show the modal? (the jsfiddle does not contain any js or jquery).

I have the following:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" /></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").css("display", "none");
            $("body").fadeIn(1000);
            $("a.transition").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                linkLocation = this.href;
                $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
            });
            function redirectPage() {
                window.location = linkLocation;
            }
        });

    </script>

    print '<li>';
         print '<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn"><img src="'.$row["image"].'" /></a>';
         print '<h4>'.$row['time'].'</h4>';
    print '</li>';
```

And this is the part I am using form the fiddle link:

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none; ">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
          <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem.</p>

          <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
          <p>This <a href="#" class="btn popover-test" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">button</a> should trigger a popover on hover.</p>

          <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
          <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" data-original-title="Tooltip">that link</a> should have tooltips on hover.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I cant figure out why the modal is not showing. There are so many different resources, it is very confusing.

Comment: did you added jquery dependency ?

Comment: No I did not, which one is it

Comment: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>`
 add this line

Comment: put this dependency above bootstrap.js

Comment: I added it in, and still no difference

Comment: did you added any more javascript code

Comment: Yes, I do have js code - adding it in

Comment: modal button should be <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

Comment: But How do I adapt it so it takes place when I click a string or a picture instead? I assumed that the whole image behaves as one big button in this case

Comment: you forgot data-target="#myModal" i guess

Comment: Still does not work.. I cant understand why, is it a conflict with the different dependencies? theres so many different methods online and none of them give the complete code (such as jquery portions). Also I think href="#myModal" takes care of the target

Comment: try to use this site: http://www.layoutit.com/. you can drag and drop functions there and you can just copy paste the html code. there is a modal there under javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to include jQuery as bootstrap relies on it for various animations, such as the show fade modal you are using.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ok, sorry about this. Just curious, though. How did my answer not answer his question? "Am I supposed to use jquery to actually show the modal? (the jsfiddle does not contain any js or jquery).". even though jsfiddle was in fact using jQuery so I knew this is where he was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use Jquery.min.js and Bootstrap.js and Bootstrap.css

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/vy4prrof/)**

```
<input type="image" id="btn1" src="https://www.google.co.in/search?q=image&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=GM85VfaUA8vs8AWZ0IC4AQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653#tbm=isch&q=button&imgrc=Bi3BrxfrMargwM%253A%3BChPBZrkfIvNRmM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmygimptutorial.com%252Fimages%252Fbutton-with-reflection%252F11.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmygimptutorial.com%252Fweb-20-button-with-reflection%3B498%3B169" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" 
               data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                  &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
               This Modal title
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            Add some text here
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
               data-dismiss="modal">Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
               Submit changes
            </button>
         </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

       <div>

$('#btn1').click(function(){

     $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a link that has all of the code which makes it easier to understand:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php